# Extracting value of a node in Java using contains with JsonPath in RestAssured

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have to extract value of book title using JsonPath in RestAssured in Java from following json response

```
  { 
   "spec": {
        "groups": [
          {
            "name": "book",
            "title": "classic-books:1.0.2"
           },.......
          ]
         }
     }
```

I am looking to use contains to get the book with a specific title.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have `response` with JSON in it:

```
response.body().jsonPath().get("spec.groups[i].title");
```